# UNIX domain socket: is there such a thing as a "busy" signal?

Tags: sockets, unix-socket

Can a *Client* pushing data through a UNIX domain socket ( AF_UNIX type ) be signaled *busy* if the receiving end cannot cope with the load?

OR

Must there be a Client-Server protocol on top of the socket to handle flow control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you include this in the protocol, there is no way for the server to tell the client to pause sending the information.

Comment: So in effect sockets are FIFO with no flow-control: an upper-layer protocol is needed for flow-control (if required).

Comment: TCP/IP doesn't know too much.  Writing a handler for control messages (you have to write these too) is the only way to do this.

Comment: @Jean-Lou: that is correct. `AF_UNIX` provides absolutely no flow control semantics. The underlying device may provide buffer overflow conditions that will result in `send()` returning an error but that is device specific.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong.  If the AF_UNIX socket is opened with SOCK_STREAM, then the server can simply stop reading from the socket; the client will then block on send() or write() until the server is ready to read more.  If the client doesn't want to block, it can use select() to see if the server is ready for more data yet.

Answer (score 9):

You can definitely do a blocking send to a UNIX Domain socket.  If the receiving side's receive buffer is full, or if the number of outstanding (undelivered) send socket buffers is too high, the sender will block.

SOCK_STREAM UNIX Domain Sockets work like TCP sockets.  SOCK_DGRAM UNIX Domain Sockets work like UDP, except that UNIX Domain datagrams have guaranteed, in-order delivery, whereas UDP sockets can be re-ordered or dropped.  (Also, UNIX Domain Sockets can be used to send file descriptors and pass user credentials between processes, neither of which can be done with TCP, UDP, or pipes.)

So, because in-order delivery is guaranteed by all types of UNIX Domain Sockets, the receiver can just stop receiving when it is busy doing other things, and the sender will be automatically blocked when there's no more buffer space available (or will be notified that there's no more buffer space, if they requested non-blocking operation on their socket).  Then, when the receiver starts receiving again, the sender will be allowed to send more.

Comment: Is there some way to utilise XON/XOFF?

Comment: You can use whatever protocol you want over the top, and that can include the sending of XON/XOFF characters.  But the kernel won't do anything special with them for you.  It just passes them through like any other byte.

Answer (score -2):

Other than the server having some knowledge of when it is 'busy' and sending a specific signal back (e.g. HTTP's 503 Service Unavailable). You can also set up the client side connection to timeout after a certain length of time, and if you get a timeout event, interpret that as the server is busy.

Comment: ... and this behavior is generic to sockets in general *or* specific to AF_INET?  (I am asking because of your example using HTTP)

Comment: PS the ETIMEDOUT is what you'd get from the socket 'connect' call if it wasn't able to make a connection within the given timeout time; setsockopt SO_SNDTIMEO with a time is the way you'd configure that (if you didn't want the default).

Comment: Then again, the host might actually be down.  Having your client sit in this sort of state is very misleading to those monitoring the process.  (assuming it's mission critical)

Comment: There's no need to time-out on an AF_UNIX connection.  Packet delivery is guaranteed unless the recipient closes their socket.  To do flow control, just stop receiving packets and they will queue up until you are ready to start receiving them again.  If the queue "fills up", eventually the sender will be stopped from sending (a call to a send function will block or return EAGAIN).  Polling (using poll, select, etc.) will indicate that the sender's socket is not writeable.  When the receiver starts receiving again, the sender socket will become writeable again.  No need for app-layer protocol.